# Need help in Installing apache in AIX7.1

Tags: apache-http-server, aix

I want to install apache 2.4.x in our AIX server which is having apache1.x that was installed very long back.

I downloaded the apr & apr utils in sourcelib of apache then downloaded pcre and tried to install pcre using
`./configure --prefix=/app/dev/vista/apache2.4/pcre`
It failed with error

> configure: error: Invalid C++ compiler or C++ compiler flags

```
rpm -qa | grep gcc
libgcc-4.2.0-3.ppc
gcc-4.2.0-3.ppc
libgcc-4.8.3-1.ppc
```

Then I tried below option through which I am able to install pcre but really dont know how this option resolved it.

```
./configure --prefix=/app/dev/vista/apache2.4/pcre --disable-cpp
```

Next I ran below command to compile apache

```
./configure --prefix=/app/dev/vista/apache2.4 --with-included-apr --with-included-apr-util --with-pcre=/app/dev/vista/apache2.4/pcre --enable-mpms-shared='prefork worker' --enable-mods-shared=most
```

followed by make command. This make command ran for long time and got below error

```
ld: 0711-224 WARNING: Duplicate symbol: .bcopy
ld: 0711-224 WARNING: Duplicate symbol: .memmove
ld: 0711-345 Use the -bloadmap or -bnoquiet option to obtain more information.
ld: 0711-317 ERROR: Undefined symbol: .EC_curve_nid2nist
collect2: ld returned 8 exit status
make: 1254-004 The error code from the last command is 1.
Stop.
make: 1254-004 The error code from the last command is 1.
Stop.
make: 1254-004 The error code from the last command is 1.
Stop.


rpm -qa | grep openssl
openssl-1.0.1j-1.ppc
```

Request anyone's help here to get apache 2.4.x installed in AIX. We usually manage Linux apache package, This is the only server we need to work on AIX that we have to install opensource because application having dedicated FileSystem and wont be using the default location.

Comment: Do you have the "openssl.base" package installed? (`lslpp -L openssl.base`)

Comment: You also have to install package `openssl-devel`. (The same is true for every dependency,)

Answer (score 1):

Thanks Jeff & Lorinczy , it related to openssl only. I was trying to install higher version of apache in lower version of openssl which caused the issue.